# Setting 127.0.0.1 as relying party trust

Tags: localhost, adfs2.0

I am working on an application that is AD FS backended. I have created the controller to direct to the AD FS login page but when I sign in I am unable to browse to 127.0.0.1

How can I set up 127.0.0.1 so that it is a trusted party and redirects to there after sign on. I already have this set up on the AD FS server but I cant seem to set 127.0.0.1 as my development URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Windows Azure Emulator uses internal emulated Load Balancer (LB). This emulated LB binds to 127.0.0.1 port 80 (if port 80 is already taken it uses port 81)
2. Windows Azure Tools are dynamically creating a virtual IP address for every instance of a webrole you have. These dynamic IP Addresses are 127.255.0.X, where X is the logical number of the instance (0, 1, 2, etc...).
3. Windows Azure tools creates a website in the local IIS, with binding of 127.255.0.X and port 82

I had to set the realm and audience URI of the project to 127.255.0.0 (as this was the first role)